# Why does statement with two operands need to be above statements with one operand for correct output?

Tags: swift

When I create incorrect properties and put

```
else if username != "tigerclaw" && password != "888love" {
print("Re-enter username and password")
}
```

at the bottom of my block Xcode doesn't print out "Re-enter username and password" when entry is incorrect.

Is it because statements with equal number of operands need to be one after the other? Because this works.

```
let username: String = "2igerclaw"
let password: String = "x88love"

if username == "tigerclaw" && password == "888love" {
print("Acess Granted")

} else if username != "tigerclaw" && password != "888love" {
print("Re-enter username and password")


} else if username != "tigerclaw" {
print("Re-enter username")

} else if password != "888love" {
print("Re-enter password")

}
```

Comment: "at the bottom of my block" - post the entire block, don't make us guess.

Comment: This is my block. That's all there is. Bottom of my block is just that. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: It's not all there is, if it starts with `else`. It's OK, though, if you don't need help, you don't have to make your question clear.

Comment: So you are at my house and can see my playground? lol it's ->ALL<- there dude. What do you want me to do? Make up some more code for you lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an `else if` to connect all of these statements. When you are using the `else` syntax, the condition will only be checked if the prior condition is not evaluated to `true`. For example:

```
if (true) {
  // This code will execute because true is, well true.
} else (true) {
  // This code WILL NOT execute, because the else statement will never be checked because we fell inside the first conditional.
}
```

If you would like to execute both, then you need to separate the statements. For example:

```
if (true) {
  // This will be excuted because true is, well true.
}

if (true == true) {
    // This will also be executed because true is still true and we are not limiting it by the else.
}
```

Comment: ok but originally that line was at the bottom of my block and I set the username and password variables to incorrect values like shown above. So it should've run going by what you said because the prior conditions were not true. Xcode should've printed out "Re-enter username and password".